# Proof of $\lim_{t\to\infty} t \mu(\{x: f(x) \geq t\}) = 0$ for $f \geq 0 $ integrable

Tags: integration, measure-theory, proof-verification, convergence-divergence, lebesgue-integral

I am having some trouble proving this statement. This is what I have done, but I don't know if my reasoning is right or if I'm missing rigor.

For $f \geq 0 $ integrable on the measure space $(X, \mathcal{A},\mu)$, it is true that
$$\lim_{t\to\infty} t \mu(\{x: f(x) \geq t\}) = 0$$

By the definition of the measure of a subset:

$$t \mu(\{x: f(x) \geq t\}) = t \int \chi_{\{x:f(x)\geq t\}} = \int t\chi_{\{x:f(x)\geq t\}} \leq \int f\chi_{\{x:f(x)\geq t\}} \leq \int f = \int|f| < \infty$$

Where the first inequality is due to the fact that on these sets, by definition $f(x) \geq t$ so $t \chi_{\{x:f(x)\geq t\}} \leq f\chi_{\{x:f(x)\geq t\}}$

Let $g_t(x)= t \chi_{\{x:f(x)\geq t\}} \to g(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{lr}
        \infty, & f(x)\geq\infty\to f(x)=\infty\\
        0, & f(x) < \infty
        \end{array}\right\}$

Now, since $f$ is integrable that means that $\mu(\{x: f(x)\notin \mathbb{R}\}) = 0$ otherwise we would find that $\int f = \int |f|=\infty$

Now $f$ is integrable, and it bounds $g_t$ for all $t$, and each $g_t$ is trivially measurable.

Therefore, we can use the Dominated Convergence Theorem and

$$\lim_{t\to \infty} t \mu(\{x:f(x)\geq t\}) = \lim_{t\to \infty}\int g_t = \int \lim_{t\to \infty} g_t = \int g=0$$ since $f(x) \notin \mathbb{R} $ almost nowhere.

The bit I am unsure of is the fact that an integrable non-negative $f$ implies that it is real-valued almost everywhere.

Comment: If $f$ takes value $\infty$ on a set of positive measure, then $f$ is not integrable. You may assume that $f$ is real-valued.

Comment: That's what I said: that $f(x) = \infty$ almost nowhere, or in a set of measure $0$. Is the proof correct then?

Comment: The dominated convergence theorem is applicable to "sequence" of functions only.

Comment: I used the theorem for the sequence of functions $\{g_t\}$

Comment: $(g_t)$, indexed by positive real number $t$ is not a sequence. There are uncountably many measurable functions in $\{g_t \mid t>0\}$.

Answer (score 6):

Let $(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$ be a measure space. Let $f:X\rightarrow[0,\infty)$
be an integrable function. We go to prove that $\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}t\mu\left(\left\{ x\in X\mid f(x)\geq t\right\} \right)=0$.

Proof: Let $(t_{n})$ be an arbitrary sequence with $0\leq t_{1}\leq t_{2}\leq\ldots$
and $t_{n}\rightarrow\infty$. By Heine theorem, it suffices to show
that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}t_{n}\mu\left(\left\{ x\in X\mid f(x)\geq t_{n}\right\} \right)=0$.
(Remark: The axiom of choice is needed.) Denote $A_{n}=\left\{ x\in X\mid f(x)\geq t_{n}\right\} $.
Note that 
\begin{eqnarray*}
t_{n}\mu(A_{n}) & = & \int_{A_{n}}t_{n}d\mu\\
 & \leq & \int_{A_{n}}fd\mu\\
 & = & \int1_{A_{n}}fd\mu.
\end{eqnarray*}
Note that $|1_{A_{n}}f|\leq|f|$ and $f$ is integrable. By the Lebesgue
Dominated Convergence Theorem, we have that $\lim_{n}\int1_{A_{n}}fd\mu=\int\lim_{n}1_{A_{n}}fd\mu=0$
because $1_{A_{n}}f\rightarrow0$ pointwisely.

It follows that $\lim_{n}t_{n}\mu(A_{n})=0$.

Answer (score 3):

\begin{align*}
\mu(f=\infty)&=\mu\left(\bigcap_{n}(f\geq n)\right)\\
&\leq\dfrac{1}{n}\int f,
\end{align*}
taking $n\rightarrow\infty$, we have $\mu(f=\infty)=0$.